# Find ToolTip Popup in Logical or Visual Tree

Tags: c#, wpf

Say I have a `ToolTip` with a style specified in XAML like this:

```
<Button Content="Click me" ToolTip="Likes to be clicked">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                        <StackPanel Background="Wheat" Height="200" Width="200">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TxbTitle" FontSize="24" Text="ToolTip" Background="BurlyWood" />
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Given I have a reference to the `Button` and that the `ToolTip` is showing, how can I find the `Popup` of the `ToolTip` (and later look for its visual children, e.g. `TxbTitle`)?

**Update:**

Based on [pushpraj's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24596864/617658) answer I was able to get a hold on the (full) visual tree, and it looks like this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PopupRoot
  System.Windows.Controls.Decorator
    System.Windows.Documents.NonLogicalAdornerDecorator
      System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip
        System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
          System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock (TxbTitle)
          System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter
            System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
      System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer
```

Here I can find the `TxbTitle` `TextBlock`.

(The logical tree like this:)

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup
  System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip
    System.String
```

pushpraj's answer is however based on that I can get hold of the `ToolTip` instance. What I have got is the `Button` only, and `Button.ToolTip` property returns the string `"Likes to be clicked"`, not the `ToolTip` instance.

So more specifically, the question is, can I get hold of the `ToolTip` *or* the `Popup` in some way when all I've got is the `Button`.

(Crazy idea: is there some way to enumerate all open `Popup`s?)

Comment: At what event you want to access it?

Comment: It's not an event. I'm working on a "tool" where I want the information, and it's accessing the elements from another thread. But also I'm interested for pure understanding...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `ToolTip` is a kind of `Popup` which hosts the tooltip content

And since a Popup is hosted in a separate window so it have it's own logical and visual tree

for your information below are the Visual and Logical tree for a tooltip

**Visual Tree**

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PopupRoot
  System.Windows.Controls.Decorator
    System.Windows.Documents.NonLogicalAdornerDecorator
      System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip
```

**Logical Tree**

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup
  System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip
```

Note: since popup has it's own root so it may not be accessible from main window's visual or logical tree.

**To find a popup of tool tip**

I have used attached properties to find the popup for a tooltip

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{

    public class ToolTipHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsEnabled.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(ToolTipHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false,OnEnable));

        private static void OnEnable(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToolTip t = d as ToolTip;

            DependencyObject parent = t;
            do
            {
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
                if(parent!=null)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(parent.GetType().FullName);
            } while (parent != null);

            parent = t;

            do
            {
                //first logical parent is the popup
                parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
                if (parent != null)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(parent.GetType().FullName);
            } while (parent != null);

        }  
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<Button Content="Click me" ToolTip="Likes to be clicked">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}" 
               xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="l:ToolTipHelper.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                        <StackPanel Background="Wheat" Height="200" Width="200">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TxbTitle" FontSize="24" Text="ToolTip" Background="BurlyWood" />
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

I have added the newly created attached property to tooltip style `<Setter Property="l:ToolTipHelper.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>`

**Retrieve ToolTip instance from code behind**

In event you can not specify the style or template of style from xaml then code behind is your way to retrieve the tooltip instance

sample code

```
    Style style = new Style(typeof(ToolTip), (Style)this.FindResource(typeof(ToolTip)));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ToolTipHelper.IsEnabledProperty, true));
    this.Resources.Add(typeof(ToolTip), style);
```

code above creates a style object for tooltip and adds a setter for `ToolTipHelper.IsEnabledProperty` and inject the same style to the resources of the window

as result the property changed handler `OnEnable` will be invoked in the `ToolTipHelper` class when ever the tooltip is required to be displayed. and the dependency object in the handler will be the actual tooltip instance which you may further manipulate.

Comment: Nice answer (+1) and it helps with my understanding. I have updated my question with findings based on your answer. However, your code assumes I have access to the XAML and unfortunately, I don't have that luxary... Se my update to the question.

Comment: If you can access the button or any parent element via code behind then what you can do is to inject a style for tool tip to the root element's resource with the setter for `l:ToolTipHelper.IsEnabled` and that will bring the tooltip popup to you whenever it is opened. I added sample code in answer.